# Alternative to youtube-dl - How to download videos from yotube/vmeo and similar websites

Tags: youtube

So I wrote a GUI for youtube-dl and it looks great. But I am in constant "worry" that youtube-dl might just stop working one day or something like when it got taken down might happen.

As my app is fully dependent on youtube-dl I would like to know if there are good alternatives to it just to be safe.

And what if I wanted to write a program to download videos from youtube, where would I start? There are several youtube downloader programs that are really good, so how are they are downloading the videos, what technology are they using?

Comment: If the programs are open source (e.g. youtube-dl is open source) you can check how they do it yourself. Just examine the source code.

Answer (score 2):

[yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/)

From the yt-dlp page:

> yt-dlp is a youtube-dl fork based on the now inactive youtube-dlc. The main focus of this project is adding new features and patches while also keeping up to date with the original project.

If all of the youtube-dl forks stopped working because of a change at YouTube, then the hundreds of people who contribute to those forks will be the first to know about alternative software. So, paying attention to those people is the best way to stay informed.